# C# SOAP Service no parameters in WSDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, soap

I´ve followed this tutorial for SOAP Service in .net-core: [creating-soap-web-services-dot-net-core-tutorial](https://dottutorials.net/creating-soap-web-services-dot-net-core-tutorial/)

And now I have the following code, but the generated client does not has any parameter. The Response-Class was generated (you can see at the buttom) but not the request-class. I think there has to be some extra annotation or something like that but can not find any solution on the internet. May someone share a solution or an other tutorial for SOAP Services on .net-core or .net5?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestResponse TestMethod(TestRequest request);
}

[DataContract]
public class TestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Test { get; set; }

}
```

Here the implementation of the interface:

```
public class TestService : IService
{
    public TestResponse TestMethod(TestRequest request)
    {
        return new TestResponse { Test = request.Test };
    }
}
```

The generated client, does not generate a mehtod with parameter:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.TestMethodResponse> ServiceReference1.IService.TestMethodAsync(ServiceReference1.TestMethodRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.TestMethodAsync(request);
    }
    
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.TestMethodResponse> TestMethodAsync()
    {
        ServiceReference1.TestMethodRequest inValue = new ServiceReference1.TestMethodRequest();
        return ((ServiceReference1.IService)(this)).TestMethodAsync(inValue);
    }
```

Thats how I call it:

```
        var client = new ServiceReference1.TestService();

        client.TestMethodAsync();
```

And at last the generated respnse-class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TestResponse", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class TestResponse : object
{
    
    private string TestField;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TestField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.TestField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you mention "tutorial", are you aware that WCF is old tech and generally nobody uses it for new projects anymore? I'm not saying you don't have a reason for learning it, but your time might be better spent on learning Web API or gRPC.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes I´m aware of that. But the third party uses SOAP for its purpose and want to be called by soap-client and if thats not anothe they want to re-call a soap-service for there responsse.

Comment: A request may or may not contain a body.  When you add a body you use a POST.  The c# classes are the body data.  When you send a Post the c# classes are serialize usually using JSON or XML.  When you receive a response the Controller Deserializes the body using JSON or XML.  A request the parameters are either in the HTTP Headers or part of the URL (the parameters are after a question mark in the URL).